# Count Documents in mongoose in single query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const postsCount = await Post.find(query).countDocuments();
const allPosts = await Post.find(query)
      .populate('likes')
      .skip(startIndex)
      .limit(noOfRecordsPerPage)
      .sort({ createdAt: 'desc' });
```

I am querying two times in Database to find the total document count . How can i do this with a single query to the database ?

Comment: how about extract the find part and do `const queryResponse = Post.find(query);` first the use queryResponse below

Comment: @Mallik. Your below data looks similar to mine and it works

Comment: Not sure @EricWong . Not tried it yet but the below response by Mallik & Kunal works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

```
//you can use aggregation pipeline and $facet to combine two DB requests into one
//Actual Code output from windows Mongoshell/Command Line Interface(CLI)
> print("mongoDB",db.version())
mongoDB 4.2.6
> db.groups1.aggregate([
... {$facet:{
...   "docCount":[
...     {$group:{
...       _id:null,
...       count:{$sum:1}
...       }
...      }
...     ],
...   "allDocs":[
...      {$match:{}}
...      ]
...  }
...  }
... ]).pretty();
{
        "docCount" : [
                {
                        "_id" : null,
                        "count" : 4
                }
        ],
        "allDocs" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd7"),
                        "uid" : 1,
                        "group_id" : "g1"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd8"),
                        "uid" : 1,
                        "group_id" : "g2"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd9"),
                        "uid" : 2,
                        "group_id" : "g2"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f817d142689512ef0bd3bd1"),
                        "uid" : 2,
                        "group_id" : "g3"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Comment: Thanks Mallik ! It works for me . Your data looks fine and is similar to mine . Can you share some information regarding performance of using find() two times and using $facet instead of that.

Comment: Executing find() two times as you said makes two trips to DB. which is not recommended. Individual queries in the find the following plans are selected. 1 . count: "stage" : "RECORD_STORE_FAST_COUNT", 2. for find all docs: COLLSCAN is seen. on the other hand, $facet will combine both into one DB request that is better than two requests. Aggregate and $facet using EOF winning stage, but the execution time metrics are nearly the same for both the case. I believe EOF scans are better than COLLSCAN. Hence the aggregation query is preferable

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet) aggregation stage to combine multiple nested pipelines into your master pipeline.

Here's a working code of the above idea -

```
const countPipeline = [
    {
        $match: query
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            count: '$count'
        }
    }
];

const postPipeline = [
    {
        $match: query
    },
    {
        $skip: startIndex
    },
    {
        $limit: noOfRecordsPerPage
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            createdAt: -1
        }
    }
];

const pipeline = [
    {
        $facet: {
            posts: postPipeline,
            count: countPipeline
        }
    }
];

const results = await Posts.aggreagate(pipeline).exec();
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal ! Works perfect for me. Just curious what is the performance change if i use the query two times above or if i use $facet ?

Comment: How can i use the populate with this aggregate in mongoose ?

Comment: @ManishKumar Use the lookup stage, for referencing `likes` collection